# Routers from different ISPs

Tags: wireless-router

Are routers from different ISPs interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

(im assuming you mean the router/modems that isps often supply free)

it depends. Usuaully yes, but some modems that come free from ISPs may have your username / password and other details hard coded into it.

also, you may find one ISP uses a technology like PPPoA for adsl and anouther PPPoE. Often you can change in teh router's configuration, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

Routers, sure. Modems, not so much. Cable modems work with cable ISPs, DSL modems work with DSL loops, and ISDN/PRI modems work with digital loops.